# Skip first line in 2D list and use values

Tags: python, list, csv, compare

I am working on a project and I have two csv files that I have converted into 2D lists. I have List1 with a certain number of bore holes within a certain area, and List2 which has corresponding multiple values to work out averages, minimums and maximums. I am having trouble as I think the function is:

1. Not skipping the titles of the values in the list, and as a result not getting an integer
2. Possibly not even comparing the two lists as I keep getting stuck at step 1

What I have so far is this:

```
def height(bReader, dataList):
    print "Height function ran, but no result"
    # bReader is bores inside polygon
    # dataList BORE_DATA.csv as 2D list
    avgHeight = 0
    minN = 9e99
    maxPh = 0
    numCount = 0
    for row in bReader:
        for row2 in dataList:
            if row[0] == row2[0]:
                if row2[1] == '':
                    if row2[1][0] == '<':
                        row2[1] = row2[1][:1]
                avgHeight += row2[4]
                numCount += 1

                print row2[4]
                # Checks the minimum values of Nitrogen

                if row2[6] < minN:
                    minN = row2[6]

                 # Checks the maximum values of Phosphorous

                if row2[5] < maxPh:
                    maxPh = row2[5]


                if lastID != row2[0]:
                   # Checks for final value before moving to next bore
                    aveHeight = avgHeight / numCount
                    print row[0]
                    print "Average Water Level" + aveHeight
                    print "Minimum Nitrogen" + minN
                    print "Maximum Phosphorous" + maxPh
                    avgHeight = 0
                    minN = 9e99
                    maxPh = 0
                    numCount = 0
                lastID = row[0]
```

This is the traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lounge\Desktop\V2\ReRun V2.py", line 39, in main
    height(levelsList, bdataList)
  File "C:\Users\Lounge\Desktop\V2\ReRun V2.py", line 263, in height
    for row in bReader:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Sample Data:

List1 Data

```
REFERENCE   EASTING NORTHING    TOC ELEVATION (m)
61610628    384835  6489341         20.24
```

List2 Data

```
BORE REF NR BORE NAME   SAMPLE DATE    water level (m)  TDSolids (mg/L) pH  N (mg/L)    P (mg/L)
61610628    JP20B   23/06/2000              3.71        430      8.8        0.28        0.007
61610628    JP20B   27/10/2000              3.18        610      7.2        1.3        0.019
```

Comment: *"having trouble"* - what exactly does that mean?

Comment: A traceback, or sample data would be invaluable.  If you're really just having trouble with the first line being wrong then `cols = dataList.pop(0)` would remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes to the program to make it run. The main points to consider are:

- Any values that are to be compared numerically must be converted to an appropriate data type as they will be strings by default if imported from csv;
- To get the maxPH you need to check of > not <
- I have moved the summary information for each bore outside of the inner loop which avoids the need to check if the id has changed;
- I have also initialised the ave, max, min variables inside the outer loop so that they are reset for each bore;
- From the data you provided it looks like the water level should be `row2[3]` not `row2[4]`;
- I have removed the logic logic around checking `if row2[1] == '':` as it appears to be redundant.

Here is the revised code:

```
def height(bReader, dataList):
    print("\nIn height function...")
    # bReader is bores inside polygon
    # dataList BORE_DATA.csv as 2D list
    for row in bReader:
        # initialise measurements for each bore
        avgHeight = 0
        minN = 9e99
        maxPh = 0
        numCount = 0

        for row2 in dataList:
            if row[0] == row2[0]:
                avgHeight += float(row2[3])
                numCount += 1

                print("Water level: {0}".format(row2[3])) # water level

                # Checks the minimum values of Nitrogen
                if float(row2[6]) < minN:
                    minN = float(row2[6])

                 # Checks the maximum values of Phosphorous
                if float(row2[5]) > maxPh:
                    maxPh = float(row2[5])

       # Checks for final value before moving to next bore
        aveHeight = avgHeight / numCount
        print row[0]
        print("Average Water Level: {0}".format(aveHeight))
        print("Minimum Nitrogen: {0}".format(minN))
        print("Maximum Phosphorous {0}".format(maxPh))
        avgHeight = 0
        minN = 9e99
        maxPh = 0
        numCount = 0


# added below for test
import csv

# create file objects and readers
f1, f2 = open('list1.csv', 'rb'), open('list2.csv', 'rb')
r1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
r2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

# create lists from readers
l1 = [[col for col in row] for row in r1]
l2 = [[col for col in row] for row in r2]

# check first couple of rows from lists
print('\nSample data from list 1\n' + '-'*23) 
for row in  l1[:2]: print(row)
print('\nSample data from list 2\n' + '-'*23) 
for row in l2[:3]: print(row)

# call function without headings from first rows
height(l1[1:], l2[1:])
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Sample data from list 1
-----------------------
['REFERENCE', ' EASTING NORTHING', ' TOC ELEVATION (m)']
['61610628', ' 6489341', ' 20.24']

Sample data from list 2
-----------------------
['BORE REF', ' NR BORE NAME', ' SAMPLE DATE', ' water level (m)', ' TDSolids', '(mg/L) pH', ' N (mg/L)', ' P (mg/L)']
['61610628', ' JP20B', ' 23/06/2000', ' 3.71', ' 430', ' 8.8', ' 0.28', ' 0.007']
['61610628', ' JP20B', ' 27/10/2000', ' 3.18', ' 610', ' 7.2', ' 1.3', ' 0.019']

In height function...
Water level:  3.71
Water level:  3.18
61610628
Average Water Level: 3.445
Minimum Nitrogen: 0.28
Maximum Phosphorous 8.8
```

Hopefully this resolves the issues for you.

Comment: @Matt Button I have revised my answer to try to resolve issues with the logic that lead to incorrect results as well as issues that raised Python errors.

Comment: Turns out I had an indent error, so some of the values are displaying now, I just am tinkering with the average water level output. Thanks very much though, the code was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

From the trace, it seems the argument you are passing to the function is not a list, but a function. The code where you call `height(...)` would be where the error is.

Sorry for not posting this as a comment, I do not have the reputation to do so.